# Can't get Autohotkey to evaluate variable in an if-statement

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to get Autohotkey to evaluate a variable that is assigned from the Clipboard and then do something based on what the variable is. Here's the code:

```
^j::
    Clipboard := ""           ; Must start off blank for detection to work.
    WinActivate, ahk_exe Excel.exe

    Send, ^c                        ; Copy text into Clipboard
    ClipWait, 2                     ; wait for it to be copied
    Course := Clipboard             ; Fetch the text into variable
    Clipboard := ""                 ; Reset Clipboard

    MsgBox %Course%                 ; To test is Course is "103"

    if ( Course == 103 ) 
    {
        Correct_Num := 105
        Correct_Title := Art Appreciation
    } 

    send, {Tab}
    send, {Tab}
    send, {Tab}
    send, %Correct_Num%
    send, {Tab}
    send, %Correct_Title%
```

The if statement is not detecting that `Course == 103` despite the MsgBox showing 103. I've tried writing the statement with 103 in quotations, I've tried the `IfEqual`. Not sure what else to do.

Comment: The code works for me. You must be copying something that isn't `103`.

Comment: @2501 perhaps. When I print the variable Course to a message box it reads out as 103. AHK doesn't have a way to call something an integer does it? It sure looks like 103

Comment: Actually, when I commented out the `WinActive` and had `103` in Notepad it did work. I'll see if I can format the cell in Excel as a number, but it should already be doing that I'd think

Comment: Maybe its as simple as trimming the non-printing characters like so: `Course := Trim(Clipboard)`.  You might also use the `WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Excel.exe` statement per @user3419297's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the variables (Clipboard, Course, Correct_Num and Correct_Title) must start off blank for detection to work. Otherwise their last value remains in memory.

```
^j::
    Course := "" 
    Correct_Num := "" 
    Correct_Title := "" 
    Clipboard := ""         
    WinActivate, ahk_exe Excel.exe
    WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Excel.exe ; important
    Send, ^c                         ; Copy the preselected text
    ClipWait, 2                      ; Wait for the clipboard to contain data
    if (!ErrorLevel)                 ; If NOT ErrorLevel clipwait found data on the clipboard   
    { 
        Course := Trim(Clipboard)        ; Fetch the text into variable (as suggested by PGilm)
        Clipboard := ""                  ; Reset Clipboard
        if (Course == 103) 
        {
            Correct_Num = 105
            Correct_Title = Art Appreciation
        }
        MsgBox %Course%`n%Correct_Num%`n%Correct_Title%
    }
    else
        MsgBox, The attempt to copy text onto the clipboard failed.
return
```

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment:

```
^j::
    Clipboard := ""           ; Must start off blank for detection to work.
    WinActivate, ahk_exe Excel.exe

    WinWaitActive, ahk_exe Excel.exe ; important

    Send, ^c                         ; Copy text into Clipboard
    ClipWait, 2                      ; wait for it to be copied
    Course := Trim(Clipboard)        ; Fetch the text into variable
    Clipboard := ""                  ; Reset Clipboard

    MsgBox %Course%                  ; To test is Course is "103"

    Correct_Num =                    ; Clear variables per user3419297 so they don't
    Correct_Title =                  ; contain the results from a prior time the equality
                                     ; was satisfied (else you will get the same results
                                     ; even if Course <> 103 since those variables
                                     ; will still contain the values from earlier)

    ifEqual, Course, 103
    {
        MsgBox Course is equal to 103, Hooray!! 
        Correct_Num := 105
        Correct_Title := Art Appreciation
    } 

    send, {Tab}
    send, {Tab}
    send, {Tab}
    send, %Correct_Num%  ;  will be blank (send nothing) if course not 103
    send, {Tab}
    send, %Correct_Title%  ;  will be blank (send nothing) if course not 103

    ;  return  ;  not sure what the rest of your code does
```

Hth

Comment: I see a problem with the above code: If the variable "Course" is equal "103" you 'll get the right values for the other variables and these values will remain in the script's memory. The next time you press ^j to copy the preselected text, you 'll get the same values even if the variable "Course" isn't equal "103".

Comment: Understood, @user3419297 (and I edited above accordingly).  Of course, we don't know what the rest of OP's code does (no "return" was included).  Unless OP wants to give more/better context . . .

Comment: Ah so my answer is not any better than yours, and you were first (and I see you edited your answer to take into acct my suggestion).  I UV'd you accordingly . . .  Probably I can just delete my answer if OP confirms the `Trim(Clipboard)` made the solution work (but I'd like to get some rep for it) . . .